# SVN / Subversion 1.7 and Eclipse Subversive & JavaHL

Tags: svn, eclipse-plugin, version, subversive

I have just upgraded to TortoiseSVN 1.6.99, Build 21709, (Subversion 1.7.0, -dev). I am having problem in my Eclipse Subversive 0.7.9.I20100512-1900 & JavaHL 1.6.15. Have tried to update my Eclipse plugins. Anyone have an solution?

Error at Eclipse:

> Share project was failed.
>   Unsupported working copy format
>   svn: The path 'XXX' appears to be part of a Subversion 1.7 or greater
>   working copy.  Please upgrade your Subversion client to use this
>   working copy.

Comment: What is the current status now? tortoisesvn prompted me to upgrade, saying there is a new version available. I upgraded, and now subclipse is not working.

Comment: @Charbel, try to upgrade your subclipse or try its beta/dev version. If it can't work (which mean it does not recognize new svn format), you may need to consider to downgrade like my case.

Comment: The latest version of [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org) claims to be able to handle svn 1.7

Comment: I'm not sure how to downgrade the working copy, the scripts provided on SVN website are for versions prior to 1.7.
Also I prefer upgrading the subclipse (and the cygwin clients) but I can't seem to do it. Subclipse i seem to be running the latest version. For cygwin, i seem to have upgraded to the 1.7 version in Setup, but when I run svn --version it prints 1.6, and in both cases they complain about incompatible working copy... help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are aware of the Subversion 1.7 state? It is currently a beta-2 state and not intended for production? Furthermore it couldn't work with the working copy, cause the working copy format of 1.7 has changed and it will not upgrade your working copy automatically. If you like to use 1.7-beta-2 you have to use the JavaHL version of Subversion 1.7-beta-2 instead of 1.6.X. 
The above mentioned is also true for TortoiseSVN, cause the version you mentioned is a BETA! (as explained on the TortoiseSVN site.

Comment: My TortoiseSVN prompted me to upgrade. Not sure why it installed beta version for me. I do not see JavaHL support 1.7. Do you have the link?

Comment: no sorry. As far as i know the 1.7 is not available onyl via source code from SVN directly..May be via one of the the update-sites in eclipse?

Comment: I tried both http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/2.0/helios-site/ and http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/2.0/update-site/. The maximum I can get is 1.6.15. So no luck, maybe I should downgrade my SVN. :(

Comment: Definitely you should downgrade.

Comment: Normally I will go to http://tortoisesvn.net/, then click download page to download latest client. But today when TortoiseSVN prompted me to upgrade, that home page has provided link to download, but is actually beta. :(

Comment: As of October 19, TortoiseSVN 1.7 full has been released but still no update for Eclipse Subversive. Pretty annoying.

Comment: I was tricked into upgrading Tortoise as well as my eclipse project's working copy. And there doesn't appear to be a way to downgrade working copies from 1.7 to 1.6.

Comment: SVNKit 1.7 has been out since early this month, and can be installed via Eclipse. I've outlined the steps in my answer.

Answer (score 32):

Bear in mind that Subversive doesn't communicate with your working copy directly; it is only an interface for Eclipse. The communication runs through an SVN connector such as SVNKit or JavaHL. This is the software you should update to resolve your problem.

In my case I'm using SVNKit, which can be updated like so:

1. Make sure Eclipse's update sites are pointing to [Polarion's recommendations](http://www.polarion.com/products/svn/subversive/download.php). Here's what my update sites look like:
   [image: Subversive]
2. You'll need the latest version of Subversive SVN Connectors, so make sure the Subversive update site is enabled and let Eclipse check for updates through *Help*, *Check for updates*.

   - Check Eclipse's Installation Details to confirm that you've got Subversive SVN Connectors version `2.3.0.I20120413-1700` or later. To do so, go to *Help*, *About*, then click "Installation details".
   - If you haven't gotten a new version, you might need to uninstall the old one, and grab the new one from the Subversive update site.
3. Now you may update SVNKit. Select *Help*, *Install new software* to bring up the software installation window.
4. Select the latest SVNKit (as of this writing, 1.7.4) and install it.
   [image: Installing SVNKit 1.7.4]
5. Restart Eclipse.

If Subversive is using the wrong connector after restarting Eclipse, select the right newest one from the preferences screen (under Preferences, select *Team*, *SVN* then click the tab "SVN Connectors").

Comment: Using Indigo I could not get this to work.  The solution for me was to uninstall all svn-like modules and then reinstall subversive from the Marketplace.

Comment: SVN Kit 1.7.* has been available in the release channel for some time now, so you should just be able to grab it from the SVN Connector dialog. Checking for updates should work, but if not, uninstall Subversive and install the release version from Eclipse Indigo or Juno's built-in update site under "Collaboration".

Comment: Very nice, this fixed my Aptana Studio 3 (build 3.2.2.x)

Comment: Hi, My Eclipse already has all the latest versions for Subversive and the SVNKit as well, even than it is giving this message. What else to look for ? Thanks

Answer (score 6):

This is now solved with Subclipse 1.8 versions.

Comment: Possibly. The question was explicitly about Subversive though, not Subclipse.

Comment: This is about SVN or Tortoise Eclipse, no need for Subclipse to be mentioned here.

Answer (score 1):

Proper selection of subclipse & SVN connector will solve the problem.

I am using ecplise indigo and Tortoise SVN 1.8
The installation of Subclipse 1.10.5 & Subversion JavaHL Native Library Adapter 1.8.10 solved the problem.

refer to http://subclipse.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectProcess?pageID=p4wYuA

Answer (score 1):

Under Window->Preferences->Team->SVN, SVN Connector tab, set the svn connector to the latest SVN kit, SVNKit 1.8.0:

[image: SVNKit 1.9]

Answer (score 0):

I gone through same issue.  I tried all these.  Nothing worked.  Reason is, I am trying it on Ubuntu (Linux).  All these solutions are for windows I guess.

I know this is very old question, but in case it can help others.

I did this.

1. In stall JavaHL (`sudo apt-get install libsvn-java`)
2. After installing search for `libsvnjavahl-1.so` file using following command
   `sudo find / -name libsvnjavahl-1.so`
3. Open `eclipse.ini` file (We can find in eclipse home folder) and edit.  I use STS so `sts.ini` for me.
   Add following:
   `-vmargs
    -Djava.library.path=/path/of/libsvn/jni`

Example:
    `-vmargs
     -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni/`

This same methodology can be applied to windows also.

Reference
http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL#head-bb1dd50f9ec2f0d8c32246430c00e237d27a04fe

Answer (score 0):

Very old question but I found one of the problems related with the "Please upgrade your Subversion client to use this working copy." error.

The solution is to delete the .svn files metadata (on Windows you need to see 'hidden folders').

I had a .svn file in my root directory C:\ so all the subfolders ultimately would be related to that file. You need to go up from your working directory and check if there are any .svn files that may enter in conflict with your current project.

I just deleted my .svn file in C:\ and there were no more conflicts.