# Subversion client version confusion

Tags: svn, command-line, version, subclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [SVN / Subversion 1.7 and Eclipse Subversive & JavaHL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840221/svn-subversion-1-7-and-eclipse-subversive-javahl)

I'm using Subversion with version 1.6.5 on the server. I use Subclipse (version 1.6) in STS as a client for certain tasks, but I more commonly use a 1.7.0 subversion command-line client.

Why 1.7 for the command-line client? No good reason.

So I made a branch with the command-line client, and now when I try to use Subclipse to "Update to HEAD", it tells me:

> org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: Unsupported working copy format
>
> svn: The path 'C:\code\workspace\my_app' appears to be part of a Subversion 1.7 or greater
> working copy.  Please upgrade your Subversion client to use this working copy.

What can I do to take make this project understandable to Subclipse? Presuming that I will not have the authority to bring everything up to date, is their a way to make this project acceptable to a 1.6 client without losing progress?

The command-line client I am using is in Cygwin.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See:
http://subclipse.tigris.org/

> Subversion 1.7.0 Support
>   Subclipse 1.8.x releases are now available
>   and includes support for Subversion 1.7.0 including the new WC-NG
>   format.

Once a newer SVN client touches a working copy it upgrades the working copy layout to its new format.  You cannot go back, and you cannot mix SVN clients of different versions, be they GUI based or command-line based.  I suggest upgrading to the newer Subclipse. It will understand the new 1.7 layout.

Comment: Will the server have difficulty with the clients that are of higher versions?

Comment: No, the servers and clients are not dependent in that way.  Oftentimes a new client will add new functionality that doesn't require the server to change.  Other times a new client adds new functionality that requires the server to change, but if the server stays the same the only problem is that the new functionality will not work -- it will not break the server.  The new client stays backwards compatible with older servers.

Comment: Upgrade to WC-NG **must be done** by hand, BTW