# How to explain eclipse that project from svn if I checkout it by tortoise svn?

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, tortoisesvn

I checkout my project using tortoise svn.

I want to import it to eclipse and eclipse svn plugin must to work.

If I make java import - eclipse doesn't understand that it is project from svn.

svn plugin is installed.

**UPDATE**

I try Import-->Team-->Team Projcect Set

[image]

This thing ask me select **FILE**. What Do I need to select?

Answer (score 0):

Which svn plusing are you using and eclipse version ?

I am using Eclipse Kepler and SVN Plugin as Subversive Team Provider. It is working fine for me. I have imported project as Java project.

Comment: I have a one more simple question may sounds like silly.. After installing the SVN plugin you imported the project or before installing it.. I  have seen a issue earlier like if I import project after installing SVN plugin it worked else it is not working.. This might be your issue or as Secario told it needs connectors.

Comment: 1. install tortoise 2. checkout 3. instal svn plugun 4. import java project

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse will understand your project if and only if it contains `.classpath` file and `.project` file in project.
If you are using Maven, then first run `clean compile` and `eclipse:eclipse` commands, then import in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Use subversion. Sometimes, it may require to install newer connector. Refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840221/svn-subversion-1-7-and-eclipse-subversive-javahl)

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed svn plugin in eclipse. You can also checkout project from eclipse.
Make .psf file pointing to your repository and then make import.

`Import-->Team-->Team Projcect Set`

Open notepad paste below content(correct with your path) and save as `.psf`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<psf version="2.0">
<provider id="org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.svnnature">
<project reference="0.9.3,URL to folder you want to checkout,folder name"/>
<project reference="0.9.3,URL to another folder you want to checkout,folder name 2"/>
</provider>
</psf>
```

Comment: @gstackoverflow Included sample .psf file in answer. You can also select URL and paste the URL if you have one or two folders to checkout. psf is used when you have more folders

Comment: amazing. but now in eclipse I see folder from repository. I need to import all projects from this folder(there a lot of projects in different locations) I need that eclipse to find their all.