# SVN error "appears to be part of a Subversion 1.7 or greater working copy" with svn version 2.0.3

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

Here is it full error that I get in Eclipse Juno when I try to commit my project through SVN

```
appears to be part of a Subversion 1.7 or greater working copy.  Please upgrade your Subversion client to use this working copy.
```

I don't understand why I get this since my SVN client version is the latest one. (2.0.3)!

Comment: Did the switch from Eclipse to Android Studio a while ago so not sure. My guess is that you have a 1.7 version alongside the new one. Go to help->about (or something like that), here you should be able to find the installed plugins and, if it is the case, remove the old svn version.

Comment: http://puu.sh/fX5Yr/502a796d66.png -  here is my "about eclipse" as you can see there is only one version of svn

Comment: Have you read [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840221/svn-subversion-1-7-and-eclipse-subversive-javahl), the third answer in particular?

Comment: Do you mean this http://stackoverflow.com/a/7993745/2608488 ?

Comment: If you are refering to the SVNKit update, then I have the latest SVNKit already that being SVN 1.8.7 and that is the only one I have installed.

Comment: My whole setup http://puu.sh/fXvqf/76c1323cc5.png

Comment: Go back down to SVNKit version 1.7. That'll fix your issue. SVN 1.8 and SVN 1.7 have different working copy layouts. The error message `Subversion 1.7 or greater working copy` is a misnomer.

Comment: Had similar problem, then I realized that on my local machine I have newer version than the one on the server. So if I used svn from localhost on mounted directory, it was ok, but using svn on remote machine was causing problems.

Answer (score 4):

From Subversion 1.1 to Subversion 1.6, the layout of the Subversion client working directory did not change. In revision 1.7, it changed, and in 1.8, it changed again. This has caused a lot of consternation in people who share a working directory with more than one Subversion client.

Both Subversive and Subclipse, the two main Subversion clients for Eclipse actually pass off the work of creating the Subversion working directory to either SVNKit or to JavaHL -- what are called the _SVN Connectors. It's these two *SVN Connectors* that must match the version of your working directory. Don't check Subversive or Subclipse's version. Check out the *SVN Connector* version.

If you go to your preferences, into Team->SVN, you will see a tab for the *SVN Connector*. Check the version of your *SVN Connector* (whether JavaHL or SVNKit), and make sure you're using the right version. In your case, it should be 1.7.

The most common reason to see this error is because you're using two different Subversion clients on the same working directory (which is officially not supported, but everyone does it anyway).

For example, are you using TortoiseSVN or the Subversion command line client, and also the Eclipse client on the same working directory, you [naughty spawn](http://www.herosandwich.net/2011/12/16/friday-night-fights-naughty-spawn-you-face-the-tick/)?

**Confession time**: I do it all the time. I find there are times when it's just damn easier to use the command line client to do certain jobs rather than struggle with the Eclipse client. For example, I can do `svn log` and do a `grep` filter to quickly find the revision I want rather than going through Eclipse. If you do this type of stuff, make sure your Subversion clients are all on the same general version (1.6 vs. 1.7 vs. 1.8).

Okay, you're a good boy and don't use different Subversion clients on the same working copy. Now what happened? In that case, I suspect you accidentally changed the *SVN Connector* version without realizing it -- either through an update, or in the settings. You can have multiple *SVN Connector* versions at the same time, and I believe each project can have different ones too.

Again, check your *SVN Connector* version, and make sure it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error trying to run this command:

`svn co http://subversion.<path to trunk>/<project name>/`

from a command prompt.  I wasn't in the workspace *project* directory, just the workspace directory.  We had the correct version of 1.8, but because I was in the wrong directory, not the project directory, I got this same error as listed above.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that I copied & pasted a package from an Eclipse workspace with an older SVN client.
I didn't know that in the background, along with the package, a .svn directory was copied as well. So when I tried to commit it I got this error.
 Deleting the .svn directory solved the problem.

Answer (score -2):

[Use search before asking.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6840221/761095)

There is no Apache Subversion 2.x. Subversion 1.8 is the latest release so far. You use Subversive 2.x which should work with Subversion 1.7 and 1.8 working copies without any issues.

1. [Make sure that you actually run the latest Subversive version](http://eclipse.org/subversive/latest-releases.php),
2. Attempt upgrading your local working copy using [`svn upgrade` command](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svn/c/upgrade/),
3. Try checking out a fresh working copy from a repository and see whether you get any errors.